# Qt, clang & PortAudio: what does those errors mean?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang, linker-errors

I write a cross-platform audio processing program. It uses Qt 5 and [PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/) library. The platform is Mac OS X Yosemite, clang compiler, Qt Creator 3.4.1 IDE. I got those linker errors:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_ellie2", referenced from:
>       _main in eltst.o
>   "_hypergl", referenced from:
>       _main in ltstd.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

What does it mean and what needs to do?

Comment: Did you follow the [tutorial](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html), specifically the part about linking to `libportaudio.a`?

Comment: @nwp, Always I used `libportaudio.dylib` and all worked fine. Now I have added a large piece of open-source code and started getting the error...

Comment: Well the error means that there is some object or function called `ellie2` and `hypegl` that have been declared but not defined. Try to search the contents of the files for these texts. Then you can probably use some "jump to definition" feature to figure out where it has been declared. You can then search for the definition and see what you need to include in your project to make it link.

Comment: @nwp, my project doesn't contain these functions. And as far as I can understand, they relate to some system/compiler calls. Google also doesn't give any useful information.

Comment: @nwp, after several tests I has convinced that the problem is somewhere into the new open source code. So, now I will try to isolate small necessary parts from it and remove all the rest